# Log4j2: log stack trace without an exception

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using Log4j2, some beta-10 version or so.

It's easy to log a stack trace when you have an exception:

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
  log.error("Doing stuff went wrong", ex);
}
```

Suppose though there is no `Throwable` object available - I just realized there is a problem and want to log an error:

```
 if (stuffIsWrong()) {
   log.error("Stuff went wrong");
 }
```

How can I tell Log4j2 to log a stack trace beginning in the current method?

Comment: cant you just throw your own custom exception?

Comment: I would be catching it _right away_, really the only thing I am interested in is the stacktrace.

Comment: if stuffIsWrong then throw custom exception and inside catch statement, you log it to your file or whatever. At the end you are getting stacktrace ;)

Comment: That sounds like a hack to me, I'd like to use some "best practice" approach...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just create a new Exception

```
if (stuffIsWrong()) {
    log.error("Stuff went wrong", new Exception("Stracktracegenerator"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Seems like a hack though, is this the recommended way to do it?

Comment: A Better way would be to create your own `Exception` like `StuffWentWrongException` throw it, and catch+log it in the outer component.

Comment: I don't think that is a better way :-).  On typical JVMs, this is the most direct way to get the current thread's stack.  Take a look at how Thread.getStackTrace() is implemented ...

Comment: I mean a better way in designing the application using Exception handling instead of logging.

Answer (score 1):

Stack trace of any method can be printed by the following code:

```
for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
    System.out.println(ste);
}
```

just check your condition and if it meets then print the stack trace in logs

Comment: Sorry, I need to log the stack trace in the context of Log4j2, using an appropriate way (a "best practice" way).

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar need for a stack trace even though nothing "went wrong". I understand your reluctance to use an exception even though nothing went wrong.

In my case this was a temporary problem, I needed to find out via which sequence of calls a certain method was invoked.

To separate this stack trace from "real" exceptions I created a class extending Exception called NoProblemJustShowingStackTrace, but any name that clarifies your intention would be fine. A good name helps a little, but as developers we are so used to seeing stack traces only when a "real" exception is thrown/caught that it will still be confusing to the people reading the log. Best remove this code once the temporary problem is resolved.

Note that you don't `throw` this exception, all you do is create the object and pass it to the logger method.

---

A more permanent alternative solution is to use a [pattern layout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) with location information, like  %location, %line, %file, %class, %method. Note that this will have a large impact on performance.